# Watirwebdriver - Drag and drop using watir webdriver

Tags: watir-webdriver

I'm trying to drag and drop an element on a webpage through the below code. I can see the drag and drop, but--after couple of seconds--the dropped element is disappearing and the scenario is passed successfully.  And it didn't work as expected when I checked manually by visiting the webpage.

I've tried my_element.drag_and_drop_on target as well, but it didn't work!

```
When(/^I drag and drop Basket rule to the position slot on the emailcreate page$/) do  
  my_element = @browser.span(:text => "Abandoned Basket") 
  target = @browser.div(:class => "droparea ui-droppable ui-sortable") 
  target = @browser.div(:id => "0")   
  my_element.fire_event("onmousedown") 
  @browser.driver.action.click_and_hold(my_element.wd).perform 
  sleep 15 
  @browser.driver.action.move_to(target.wd).perform 
  sleep 15 
  my_element.fire_event("onmouseup") 
end
```

Comment: When(/^I drag and drop Basket rule to the position slot on the emailcreate page$/) do
my_element = @browser.span(:text => "Abandoned Basket")
target = @browser.div(:class => "droparea ui-droppable ui-sortable")
target = @browser.div(:id => "0")
my_element.fire_event("onmousedown")
@browser.driver.action.click_and_hold(my_element.wd).perform
sleep 15
@browser.driver.action.move_to(target.wd).perform
sleep 15
my_element.fire_event("onmouseup")
end

Comment: You will likely need to provide a page that reproduces the problem.

Comment: When you say "And it didn't work as expected when I checked manually by visiting the webpage.", do you mean that there is a bug with the application?

Answer (score 0):

Focus the Element before drag and drop
My_element.focus #and try after that